# Tweak Scrollbar Click Behavior

Tags: 20.04, gnome, scrolling

By default, when clicking a scrollbar's gutter, the middle of the bar moves to the point that was clicked. I'd prefer that it worked like in Windows, where the bar moves **toward** the mouseclick but not **to** it.

I've not found a setting for this in Ubuntu's Settings or in GNOME-Tweak. Can you recommend  a way to make this change?

- Ubuntu version: 20.04 LTS
- GNOME version: 3.36.8
- Application Theme: Yaru

Answer (score 0):

Changing that would probably require programming skills. This behavior is determined in the toolkit used for the application, for many applications in Ubuntu, that will be GTK3.

Note you can also drag the bar, and scroll with the mouse wheel or dragging the edge of the touchpad or dragging with two fingers (depending on how you configure it) to fine-tune your position.